# C# How to use a folder in a project

Tags: c#

I've honestly been researching about this for hours, and I still haven't found anything close to what I am looking for.

Basically I created a folder in my project and called it "Files". Then I added a lot of actual files to that folder, and now I want to access them via a void, but I can't get the names of them.

I've tried to display the files in a message box (just for testing purposes), so I used this:

```
public static string[] GetResourceNames()
    {
        var asm = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
        string resName = asm.GetName().Name + ".Files";
        using (var stream = asm.GetManifestResourceStream(resName))
        using (var reader = new System.Resources.ResourceReader(stream))
        {
            return reader.Cast<DictionaryEntry>().Select(entry => (string)entry.Key).ToArray();
        }
    }
```

But all it does is return an error saying the reader can't be null.

I'm trying to show it in a foreach loop like this:

```
foreach (string resourceName in GetResourceNames())
        {
            MessageBox.Show(resourceName);
        }
```

but it shows nothing.

What I'm trying to do is this:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        int totalFiles = 17;
        int currentFiles = 0;
        foreach (var file in assembly.GetManifestResourceNames())
        {
            string extractPath = functions.pathToExtract + @"\" + file;

            using (Stream s = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(file))
            using (BinaryReader r = new BinaryReader(s))
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(extractPath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
            using (BinaryWriter w = new BinaryWriter(fs))
                w.Write(r.ReadBytes((int)s.Length));
            currentFile.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { currentFile.Text = "Installing : " + file + " ( " + currentFiles + " out of "+ totalFiles + " installed )"; });
            currentFiles += 1;
        }
```

This is what I'm trying to do, and this is code is successful, but it writes the file names as: SolutionName.Files.FileName.Extension and I only want it to write as FileName.Extension

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: @Shaamaan yes, the files are registered in the solution, and no, they're not in the resources window, I have just dragged and dropped them in the "Files" folder and changed their Build Action to "Embedded Resource"

Answer (score 0):

Well, a resource file is stored with the format you've specified: `[Solution].[Folder].[File].[Extension]`.

Assuming all you really want to do is remove the initial `[Solution].[Folder]` from file names you can just use `String.Replace`.

Something like:

```
var fileName = file.Replace("[Solution].[Folder]", "");
```

Then use `fileName` for the `currentFile.Text` or for `extractPath`. Be mindful that I don't know what `functions.pathToExtract + @"\" + file` in your code produces at the moment, so it's a bit of a guess on my part, but I think this would produce a sensible path which could be used for extracting embedded resources.

Comment: currentFile.text is just a label that displays which file is being extracted, that doesn't change the output of the files

Comment: @Ghawn You could just as well use it for your `extractPath`. I've edited the answer.